# How can I extract an attribute from a list of dictionaries and run it in a loop?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a list defined in Ansible group_vars as shown below:

```yaml
ipa_ca_anchors:
  - { certmap_name: CERT1, cert_cn: 'CN=CA1, OU=ROOT', cert_file: cert1.pem }
  - { certmap_name: CERT2, cert_cn: 'CN=CA2, OU=ROOT', cert_file: cert2.pem }
```

I would first like to install the certificates by running the commands in a loop one at a time:

```ini
ipa-cacert-manage install /etc/pki/ca-trust/anchors/cert1.pem
ipa-cacert-manage install /etc/pki/ca-trust/anchors/cert2.pem
```

Then I would like to use ipa_ca_anchors variables to create a file that will ultimately look like this:

```ini
certmap CERT1       CN=CA1, OU=ROOT
CERT1:CmapLdapAttr  seeAlso
CERT1:verifycert    off
certmap CERT2       CN=CA2, OU=ROOT
CERT2:CmapLdapAttr  seeAlso
CERT2:verifycert    off
```

I tried the following:

```yaml
---
- name: Install certs
  command: "ipa-cacert-manage install /etc/pki/ca-trust/anchors/{{ ipa_ca_anchors|map(attribute='cert_file') | list }}"

- name: Populate certmap.conf
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/dirsrv/slapd-REALM/certmap.conf
    state: present
    line: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "certmap {{ ipa_ca_anchors|map(attribute='certmap_name') | list }}  {{ ipa_ca_anchors|map(attribute='cert_cn') | list }}"
    - "{{ ipa_ca_anchors|map(attribute='certmap_name') | list }}:CmapLdapAttr seeAlso"
    - "{{ ipa_ca_anchors|map(attribute='certmap_name') | list }}:verifycert off"
```

The command failed because of the [ ], and it is not looping as one at a time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The template of the command seems to be trivial

```yaml
  cmd: "ipa-cacert-manage install /etc/pki/ca-trust/anchors/{{ item.cert_file }}"
```

Testing it in the loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: cmd
      loop: "{{ ipa_ca_anchors }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  cmd: ipa-cacert-manage install /etc/pki/ca-trust/anchors/cert1.pem
  cmd: ipa-cacert-manage install /etc/pki/ca-trust/anchors/cert2.pem
```

If this is what you want run the command

```yaml
    - command: "{{ cmd }}"
      loop: "{{ ipa_ca_anchors }}"
```

- Use the filter [format](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.format) and create the template

```yaml
  content: |
    {% for i in ipa_ca_anchors %}
    {{ '%s %s %+21s' % ('certmap', i.certmap_name, i.cert_cn) }}
    {{ '%s:%s %+8s' % (i.certmap_name, 'CmapLdapAttr', 'seeAlso') }}
    {{ '%s:%s %+6s' % (i.certmap_name, 'verifycert', 'off') }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Testing it

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: content
```

gives

```yaml
  content: |-
    certmap CERT1       CN=CA1, OU=ROOT
    CERT1:CmapLdapAttr  seeAlso
    CERT1:verifycert    off
    certmap CERT2       CN=CA2, OU=ROOT
    CERT2:CmapLdapAttr  seeAlso
    CERT2:verifycert    off
```

If this is what you want write the content to a file. For example,

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.txt
        content: "{{ content }}"
```

will create the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt
certmap CERT1       CN=CA1, OU=ROOT
CERT1:CmapLdapAttr  seeAlso
CERT1:verifycert    off
certmap CERT2       CN=CA2, OU=ROOT
CERT2:CmapLdapAttr  seeAlso
CERT2:verifycert    off
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
 hosts: localhost

  vars:

    ipa_ca_anchors:
      - {certmap_name: CERT1, cert_cn: 'CN=CA1, OU=ROOT', cert_file: cert1.pem}
      - {certmap_name: CERT2, cert_cn: 'CN=CA2, OU=ROOT', cert_file: cert2.pem}

    cmd: "ipa-cacert-manage install /etc/pki/ca-trust/anchors/{{ item.cert_file }}"
    content: |
      {% for i in ipa_ca_anchors %}
      {{ '%s %s %+21s' % ('certmap', i.certmap_name, i.cert_cn) }}
      {{ '%s:%s %+8s' % (i.certmap_name, 'CmapLdapAttr', 'seeAlso') }}
      {{ '%s:%s %+6s' % (i.certmap_name, 'verifycert', 'off') }}
      {% endfor %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: cmd
      loop: "{{ ipa_ca_anchors }}"
    - debug:
        var: content

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test.txt
        content: "{{ content }}"

    # - command: "{{ cmd }}"
    #   loop: "{{ ipa_ca_anchors }}"
```

---

Q: ***"How can I use this template to append the content to an existing file?"***

A: Use [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html)

```yaml
    - blockinfile:
        dest: /tmp/certmap.conf
        block: "{{ content }}"
```

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question is how can I use this template within a role so I can append the content with the certificates to an existing file?

Comment: I added an example. Put it into a role if you want to. Open a new [mre] question if you have more 'follow-ups'.